# Which minimum version of Android supports HTML5 Local storage?

Tags: android, html, local-storage

Also, how to test if the browser in device supports local storage?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would say that HTML5 storage is supported since API Level 7 (2.1) because the method that enable it in `WebSettings` Object says it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDomStorageEnabled%28boolean%29), *but I think I'm using it on the Native browser since Android 2.0*.

```
// Javascript Test
if (typeof window.localStorage == 'object')
{
    // localStorage is supported
}
else
{
    // localStorage is not supported
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kcckq/

---

[Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-html5mobile2/) is a blog post that tells us that is Android 2.1+

---

[Here](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html#localstorage) is another article that is saying it's Android 2.0+ and giving an example on how detecting if localStorage is supported.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopheCVB. Awesome and elaborative answer. Its really more than helpful.

Comment: Just one question related to this..If am building HTML5(with local storage capability) using webview, will my be able to run on Android 2.2?

Comment: Yes, the HTML5 Storage is Compatible with Android 2.1+

Comment: Well, one caveat: Local Storage is supposed to be persistent across all browser tabs or windows. Android restricts apps to read/write within the same webview: if you write in one and try to read in another, you'll get no data. A javascript fix is here: https://github.com/didimoo/AndroidLocalStorage